# MySQL Query Returns Zero Rows

Tags: mysql, sql, set, execute, prepare

I have a query that returns 0 records however should not. My query is,

```
SET @id = (SELECT name FROM tag_type WHERE id = 1);
SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @id);
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

MySQL Tells me that:

```
SET @id := (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM tag_type WHERE id = 1);# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @id);# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s;# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

EXECUTE stmt1;# Rows: 366

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).
```

However if I run the query on it's own as:

```
SELECT name FROM tag_type WHERE id = 1;
```

Then I get the results expected. Why is this? Thanks, Nick

Comment: Are you connected to the same database when you run the two queries?  Also, you don't need `:=` for `set`.

Comment: Yes, I am and I have tried both with and without :